# kotlin-firebase-retrieving corresponding data from child selected in spinner

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am using kotlin and using and I am trying to retrieve data from a STATIC list in firebase based on a selected I have made with a spinner. I have a list which contains countries and their corresponding continent. after i select the country using a searchable spinner, I can successfully store my selection into a new child lets say country selected. however i want to also retrieve the continent to which it exists and also store that into a new child. this new child becomes part of another function e.g. i am consolidating data to show into a listview.

How do i get the continent written into the new child after the spinner selection is completed?

My Firebase node is as follows [thanks Frank for the advice on updating the tree using text]

```
[ {
  "Continent" : "Europe",
  "Country" : "UK"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Europe",
  "Country" : "France"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Europe",
  "Country" : "Netherlands"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Europe",
  "Country" : "Spain"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Asia",
  "Country" : "India"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Asia",
  "Country" : "China"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Asia",
  "Country" : "Japan"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Asia",
  "Country" : "South Korea"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Africa",
  "Country" : "South Africa"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Africa",
  "Country" : "Egypt"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Africa",
  "Country" : "Nigeria"
}, {
  "Continent" : "Africa",
  "Country" : "Morocco"
} ]
```

I have tried using the following code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
lateinit var continentchosenRef:DatabaseReference
continentchosenRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("location/continent")

    continentchosenRef.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            val continentchosen = dataSnapshot.getValue(location::class.java)
            continent = continentchosen.toString()
            //Update the UI with received data
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            iFirebaseloaddone.onFirebaseLoadFailed(error.message)
        }
    })
```

eventually i want to use the continent variable above to send the string to a new child (which already works for the country selected in the spinner).

Please help

---

I tried the follow and noticed that the country selected is a returning a null

```
continentRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
      val continentRef = continentchosenRef.child("location").orderByChild("country").equalTo(searchable_spinner_country.toString())


      continentchosenRef.addValueEventListener (object : ValueEventListener {

          override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
              for(ds in dataSnapshot.children){
     Log.d("spinner brand",searchable_spinner_country.selectedItem.toString())
                  val Continent = ds.child("Continent").getValue(String::class.java)
               val  continentselected = Continent.toString()

                  Log.d("Continent",continentselected)
              }
          }
          override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
              Log.d("continenterror","error on continent")
          }

      })
```

position in the database of location is in the first node:

```
{
  "location" : [ {
    "Continent" : "Europe",
    "Country" : "UK"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Europe",
    "Country" : "France"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Europe",
    "Country" : "Netherlands"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Europe",
    "Country" : "Spain"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Asia",
    "Country" : "India"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Asia",
    "Country" : "China"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Asia",
    "Country" : "Japan"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Asia",
    "Country" : "South Korea"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Africa",
    "Country" : "South Africa"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Africa",
    "Country" : "Egypt"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Africa",
    "Country" : "Nigeria"
  }, {
    "Continent" : "Africa",
    "Country" : "Morocco"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure, post a snippet of the actual JSON (as text, no screenshot needed). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Where in your database does the `location` node exist? You can also add a screenshot of your schema. Please also responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo, Location would be the first node in the database:

Comment: @WaseemAhmed Ok, add then a screenshot of your database schema.

Comment: @AlexMamo, I unfortunately cannot post an image. I only joined Stackoverflow yesterday and my reputation is not high enough, the website blocks me from adding images to a post

Comment: @WaseemAhmed You can use [imgbb.com](https://imgbb.com/).

Comment: @AlexMamo,https://ibb.co/8NWZ5Kj, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue that is see in your code is your reference. Assuming that `searchable_spinner_country.toString()` returns a country like `France`, please change the following line of code:

```
val continentRef = continentchosenRef.child("location")
    .orderByChild("country").equalTo(searchable_spinner_country.toString())
```

to

```
val continentRef = continentchosenRef.child("location")
    .orderByChild("Country").equalTo(searchable_spinner_country.toString())
//                 ^
```

See, I have changed the lowercase `c` with capital `C`, since in your database is stored this way.

Comment: I think is the solution for the exact question you've asked.